# Gradle - Getting socket closed exception intermittently when downloading dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I am getting socket closed exception from Gradle when it downloads dependencies from Maven repositories

```
Could not download asm-all-repackaged.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:asm-all-repackaged:2.5.0-b32)
  > Could not get resource 'https://nexus.internal/nexus/content/groups/mirror/org/glassfish/hk2/external/asm-all-repackaged/2.5.0-b32/asm-all-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar'.
     > Could not GET 'https://nexus.internal/nexus/content/groups/mirror/org/glassfish/hk2/external/asm-all-repackaged/2.5.0-b32/asm-all-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar'.
        > Socket closed
```

It seems that resource is downloaded, but Gradle build ends up abruptly with error. When I try to run the job in loop like `gradle build || while [[ $? != 0 ]]; do gradle build; done` then I end up with successful job eventually.

Any idea why this happens?

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-06-14 15:11:08 UTC
Revision:     316546a5fcb4e2dfe1d6aa0b73a4e09e8cecb5a5

Groovy:       2.4.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation 25.191-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.1 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I gave up and reinstalled entire OSX, which seems to solve the problem.

However I don't get it, I reinstalled every single Java, removed everything related to JDK, Gradle, Maven, but nothing helped.